# React Day Picker calendar overlay pops up behind other components

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

How do I make the calendar overlay popup for the react day picker input field show on top of the other form components?  The calendar is being hidden by the other form components.  Is there some sort of z-index that I can set somewhere?

```
<DayPicker.Input
    name={this.id}
    placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
    format="M/D/YYYY"
    value={this.value}
    onDayChange={this.handleDayChange.bind(this)}
    dayPickerProps={datePickerProps}
/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The overlay has a `DayPickerInput-Overlay` class which is absolutely positioned: you can add a `z-index` to that to make the overlay on the top of other elements.

Comment: Yep that worked.  .DayPickerInput-Overlay {
   z-index: 99;
}

Comment: Hi @Lambert, I have a react-typescript project that I'm trying to use react-day-picker and I have encountered the same problem. Please if you could give me a code sniped on how to use your solution. where should I create the class you mentioned and how should I add this class on <DayPicker/> element. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use [Portals](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) with a **custom overlay** component (props - **overlayComponent**) to render it **on top of everything**. But it can cause a problem with the positioning component, so I recommend use [Popper](https://material-ui.com/ru/components/popper/) of material-ui as custom overlay component because it showing in the free space area on the screen. See codesandbox example.

**Example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-glitter-c77gb?file=/src/DateRangePicker.js